# Postgres WHERE array contains empty string

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm trying to do `select * from demo where demojson->'sub'->'item' = array("")` but this doesn't work. I'd like to find the following

- All rows where `.sub.item` in the JSON column is an array containing exactly one empty string (`[""]`)
- All rows where `.sub.item` in the JSON column is an array that may contain more than one item, but at least one of the items is an empty string. (`["not empty", "also not empty", ""]`)

demojson column could contain for example

```
{ 
  "key": "value",
  "sub": {
    "item": [""]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, show JSON file or a minimum sample.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I can't validate this text as a valid json file. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * from demo 
WHERE demojson->'sub'->>'item' = '[""]';
```

Here `->>` operator allows to get JSON object field as text.

And another solution

```
SELECT * from demo 
WHERE json_array_length(demojson->'sub'->'item') = 1 AND 
      demojson->'sub'->'item'->>0 = '';
```

Here `->>` operators allows to get JSON first array element as text.

Comment: Since you're not using any wildcards in your pattern, you probably want just `= '[""]'` and  `= ''` rather than `LIKE '[""]'` and `LIKE ''`

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for suggestion, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Due JSONLint doesn't validate the supplied text example, I've used the next:

```
CREATE TABLE info (id int, j JSON);
insert into info values 
  (1, '{"key":"k1", "sub": {"item":["i1","i2"]}}'),
  (2, '{"key":"k2", "sub": {"item":[""]}}'),
  (3, '{"key":"k3", "sub": {"item":["i2","i3"]}}');
```

Using the where clause in this way, it works:

```
select * from info
where j->'sub'->>'item' = '[""]';


+----+------------------------------------+
| id |                  j                 |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  2 | {"key":"k2", "sub": {"item":[""]}} |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/VEPY57423

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM demo
WHERE demojson->'sub'->'item' = to_jsonb(ARRAY['']);
```